# I want to turn off mouse acceleration and increase the sensitivity

Tags: mouse, input-devices, mouse-pointer

I’ve heard linux mouse inputs are processed differently but it just sounds like pointer acceleration to me. So basically in windows terms, I want no mouse acceleration, and I want to multiply the inputs by x(I’m not sure what multiplier I would use). How do I do this?

I’m running Xubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Have you experimented with Mouse Speed in Settings>Devices>Mouse and Touchpad>Mouse Speed ?

Comment: @Graham yes, but I made acceleration as low as possible because that had the least(or no) acceleration.